# Real roots for analytic function

Tags: analysis

Is there a generalized criteria for checking the reality of (all) roots of analytic function ?
There are several such existing result for special case of polynomials
like Newton's identities or Hermite Sylvester theorem or insights gained from Weierstrass product of a function .
Can these methods be generalized ?

Comment: When you say "checking the reality of (all) roots " do you mean "checking that all roots of a given function are Real"? If so, you may know about Descartes' Sign Rule which is a a method of determining the maximum number of positive and negative real roots of a polynomial.

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but I do know that being able to show the roots of certain transcendental equations were real was important for some of Fourier's work on heat flow, so [this goolge search](https://www.google.com/search?q="reality+of+roots"+"Fourier") might lead you to some further ideas for searches. Also, [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reality+of+roots%22+%22Hardy%22), as I also recall that G. H. Hardy did some work of a similar type.

Comment: @NoChance yes , I mean checking for all the roots of a given equation are real .

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro yes ,sir I know of Hardy's work (Hardy's z - function )  also the Fourier work on Bessel function ( real rootedness by rational approximation ) Also , some recent works of Polya , De bruijn Csordas , Varga , Newmann , Tao and Rodgers , Dimitrov  . But they all lack generality ( because it's very hard of course ) . But is there generalized approach toward such problems ?  Because I don't know one if there's one

Comment: The zeros of $f$ entire are all real iff the zeros of $f(\frac{z-i}{z+i})$ are all on $|z|=1$ iff the Taylor series of both $\frac{1}{f(\frac{z+i}{z-i})},\frac{1}{f(\frac{z-i}{z+i})}$ have radius of convergence $1$ (replacing $1/f$ with $\log f$ this is Li's criterion for the RH)

Comment: @reuns thank you sir

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is all to advanced for me. If you know a some simple reference for the this please let me know - Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me about your mathematical background. I will tell likewise @NoChance

Comment: @AmitAkoskar I have a B.Sc. in Statistical Mathematics and Computer Science. This degree requires study of 4 Calculus courses, 2 Linear Algebra courses, Optimization, Operations Research, Real Analysis, among other topics.

Comment: @NoChance  you can start by studying the work of Poly on the subject ( you can easily get it on Google ) Furthermore you can check Fourier's work on checking reality of roots of Bessel function by rational approximation . Also you can study the following paper by De bruijn :                              https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://research.tue.nl/files/1769368/597490.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjuyL_vu6TjAhUEOI8KHetcDZoQFjACegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3KQGHZNXeK-QoMEY843fwu

Comment: @NoChance. Sorry that I don't recommend the references in chronological order but it's a good order of studying the field from my experience

Comment: @AmitAkoskar, thank you much for your help. I appreciate it.